# Can't make lock object private in static class - why?

Tags: c#

In a static class, I have a method which will edit a variable. The class is static because the class is about site detaild and so only one instance is ever required.

Anyway, thread synchronisation is required. I have a lock object, but when I make it private it and say lock (obj){} I get all sorts of errors.

Why is not possible to make the lock object private?

Comment: Can you post some of your error info - I have a private lock object in a static class that's been working fine...

Comment: What errors do you get ?  You need to make the object static too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thought, do you initialise the object statically. Try declaring:

```
private static object lockObject = new object();
```

Comment: There is no need to initialize the object to be able to compile it... It works without it too.

Comment: @Mehrdad - not sure what you mean, it will compile but it will fail at runtime with null ref exception, right?

Comment: Yeah. I meant exactly the same thing. The OP gave me the impression that "all sort of errors" includes compile time ones. Guess this was a runtime issue.

Answer (score 1):

It should work. Are you declaring it as `private static`?

```
private static readonly object lockObject = new object();

public static void Method() {
    lock(lockObject) { 
         // ...
    }
}
```